# Which denomination(s) believe(s) there are many heavens?

Tags: heaven

Which denomination(s) believe(s) there are many heavens?

Comment: This question needs to directed to a specific denomination or denominations. As stated it is almost impossible to answer, since it is pretty much an opinion question.

Comment: @CecilBeckum Well, I know the answer is "yes", because I think I have been to a Bible Study where the Bible Study teacher talks about the existence of many heavens. At least I know *that* denomination believes in multiple heavens; I just can't remember the name of the denomination. I'll see if I can find the church on the map and infer the denomination.

Comment: @CecilBeckum OK. I think it is United Methodist, but I am not entirely sure if the church group truly was United Methodist or a different church group who happens to use a United Methodist church building at the time. I was so young then.

Comment: You might just need to rephrase your question to ask if any denominations hold that belief.

Comment: @CecilBeckum Done.

Comment: I noticed that two people thought your question was worthy of an answer but not a vote. So I gave you an up vote which should have been the third and not the only vote.

Answer (score 3):

LDS theology explains the idea of heaven in terms of kingdoms of glory. The highest celestial kingdom being the place where God resides and the place where the faithful followers of Christ will dwell after the resurrection. [LDS description of Heaven](http://www.lds.org/topics/kingdoms-of-glory?lang=eng&query=kingdom%20of%20glory)

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but:

2 Corinthians 12:2 mentions "the third heaven". I think most Christians interpret this by a theory that says there are three heavens: the first heaven is the sky, i.e. where the clouds are and birds fly; the second heaven is outer space, where the stars and planets are; and the third heaven is where God lives. You can find plenty of references in the Old Testament where the word heaven is used to refer to each of the three, and it's the same word in Hebrew. I have never heard a Christian use this as part of a theory about multiple levels of the place where God lives, but maybe someone has somewhere along the line.

The Quran has a story about Mohammed being taken to heaven by an angel, and there are seven levels to heaven, with the most holy people going to the highest levels and the less holy people going to the lower levels.

There were some theories in ancient times about seven levels to heaven, based on the five planets known at the time -- Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn -- plus the Sun and Moon.